# How to apply custom css in woocommerce product page for mobile screen resolution?

Tags: css, wordpress

I am new to wordpress and I want to apply css on single product page only for changing the location of "Sale" icon. I am trying following code in custom css but its not making any changes.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px){
.single-product .woocommerce .has-product-nav span.onsale {
    top: 7rem !important;
    margin-top: 0px;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, in my opinion, it is always more concise to assign the generic css rules you need for your class and then target the viewports for mobile, tablet and large desktops.

I think that the problem you are facing is that there is already another css rule which overwrites the mobile version css rule. Remove the `!important` from your desktop's version `.single-product` if there is one.

Naturally, that does solve the issue.

```
 /* Desktop Version */
 .single-product .woocommerce .has-product-nav span.onsale {
    top: 7rem;
    margin-top: 0px;
  } 

 // set the orientation of your mobile viewport
 @media screen and (max-width: 767px) and (orientation:portrait) {
    .single-product .woocommerce .has-product-nav span.onsale {
        top: 5rem !important;
     }
   }

 @media screen and (max-width: 767px) and (orientation:landscape) {
    .single-product .woocommerce .has-product-nav span.onsale {
        top: 4rem !important;
     }
  }
```